# Linked list- compile error implication

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree

I am self-learning data structures using MIT Open Courseware. I'm doing the **6.S096-Introduction to C/C++ course** and attempting the fourth assignment.

It is based on binary search trees and I gave it a try. But the code below has errors that I don't know how to fix. The one I'm concerned about is the **unknown type** for node left and right.

Could I get some pointers?(no pun intended)

The error:

```
bintreesubete.c:7:2: error: unknown type name ‘node’
  node* left;
  ^
bintreesubete.c:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘node’
  node* right;
  ^
```

P.S. Ignore the function find_node_data. I haven't finished it yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int node_id;
    int data; 
    node* left;
    node* right;
}node;



///*** DO NOT CHANGE ANY FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***///
// Declare the tree modification functions below...
node* newNode(int data,int node_id){
    node* new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    new_node->data = data; 
    new_node->node_id= node_id; 
    new_node->right= new_node->left=NULL;  
    return new_node;
}

node* insert_node(node* root, int node_id, int data) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return newNode(data,node_id);
    else{
        node* cur;
        if(node_id<root->node_id){
            cur=insert_node(root->left,data,node_id);
            root->left=cur;                
        }
        else if(node_id>root->node_id){
            cur=insert_node(root->right,data,node_id);
            root->right=cur;
        } 
    }
    return root;
}

// Find the node with node_id, and return its data
int find_node_data(node* root, int node_id) {
    node* current; 
    for( current = root->; current->next!=NULL; 
        current= current->next){ 
    if(current->data == data) return current; 
} 
return NULL; 
}

int main() {
    /*
    Insert your test code here. Try inserting nodes then searching for them.

    When we grade, we will overwrite your main function with our own sequence of
    insertions and deletions to test your implementation. If you change the
    argument or return types of the binary tree functions, our grading code
    won't work!
    */
    int T,data,node_id;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    node* root = NULL;
    while(T-->0){
        scanf("%d %d\n",&data,&node_id);
        root=insert(root,data,node_id);
    }
    node *lol;
    node *king;
    for(lol=root;lol->left!=NULL;lol=lol->left){
        for(king=root;king->right!=NULL;king=king->right){
            printf("%d %d",lol->node_id, king->node_id);
        }
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `node* left;` --> `struct node* left;`

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a `typedef`ed identifier starts immediately *after* its definition, therefore you cannot use it *in* that definition.  Contrast with structure tags, which can be referenced even within the first declaration in which they appear:

```
struct node {
    int node_id;
    int data; 
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

I prefer that style for declaring self-referential structure types because the declaration stands on its own.  If you want also to `typedef` it then I find it clearer to do that in a separate declaration:

```
typedef struct node node;
```

... but you can do it all in one declaration if you want:

```
typedef struct node {
    int node_id;
    int data; 
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;
```

The typedef is not inherently necessary, however; it is fine to just use `struct node` directly everywhere.  Plenty of people in fact prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the typedef before.

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
  ...
  node* ..;
};
```

### OR

```
typedef struct node
{
  ...
  struct node* ..;
} node;
```

Comment: @hellowurf: if my answer solved your question ..accept it but also post your error so that future users get help reading from your question.